# Why in JavaScript, will you do `len = arr.length >>> 0`?

Tags: javascript

On Mozilla Org's website, [the polyfill code of `Array.prototype.some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some?v=example) has this line:

```
var len = t.length >>> 0;
```

What is this line for, as opposed to just

```
var len = t.length;
```

?

Comment: [What does x >>> 0 do?](//stackoverflow.com/q/4081216) and [What is the JavaScript >>> operator and how do you use it?](//stackoverflow.com/q/1822350)

Comment: Type coercion, I guess. `undefined >>> 0` is `0`

Comment: @Tushar so it basically forces `t.length` to be whatever it's actual value is to be an integer or if unable to convert to an integer it will set `len` to be `0`

Comment: the answer in the other question says, "to make sure it is positive (or non-negative)"... oh but `t.length` is always non-negative, so why still do the `>>> 0` ?